# How to combine list of dictionaries using with_items in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm working right now on simple firewall, which is simply grouped list of iptables rules. For configuration i'm using list of dictionaries, based on which files are generated, relying on template.

```
firewall_v4_input:
 - { group: "haproxy",    rule: "-p tcp -m multiport --dport 80,443 -j ACCEPT" }
 
firewall_v4_output:
 - { group: "haproxy",    rule: "-p tcp --dport 3000 -d 10.0.0.5 -j ACCEPT" }
```

Task for creating firewall "drop-ins"

```
- name: Install custom defined defined checks (ipv4)
  template:
    src: etc/firewall/4.conf.d/99-custom
    dest: /etc/firewall/4.conf.d/99-{{ item.group }}
    owner: root
    group: root
  with_items:
  - "{{ firewall_v4_input | unique | default([]) }}"
  - "{{ firewall_v4_output | unique | default([]) }}"
  - "{{ firewall_v4_forward | unique | default([]) }}"
  - "{{ firewall_v4_prerouting | unique | default([]) }}"
  - "{{ firewall_v4_postrouting | unique | default([]) }}"
```

Unfortunately in this scenario with_items is iterating over and over when group name is used multiple times.

```
ok: [proxy] => (item={u'group': u'haproxy', u'rule': u'-p tcp -m multiport --dport 80,443 -j ACCEPT'})
ok: [proxy] => (item={u'group': u'haproxy', u'rule': u'-p tcp --dport 5000 -d 10.0.0.5 -j ACCEPT'})
```

Unfortunately i haven't found a way to combine multiple lists using with_items as every list seems to be treated independently. Is there a way to iterate over unique value of key named group?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you found the time to review the given answer? If so, you might want to consider to either leave a comment (so it can be improved by its author), or, if it was helpful, to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: *"**Iterate over the unique value of the key named group.**"*

A: Concatenate the lists, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        fw: "{{ fw|default([]) + lookup('vars', item, default=[])|unique }}"
      loop:
        - firewall_v4_input
        - firewall_v4_output
        - firewall_v4_forward
        - firewall_v4_prerouting
        - firewall_v4_postrouting
```

and loop the lists in the template by the groups, e.g.

```yaml
    - template:
        src: 99-custom.j2
        dest: "99-{{ item.0 }}"
      loop: "{{ fw|groupby('group') }}"
```

```yaml
shell> cat 99-custom.j2
{% for i in item.1 %}
{{ i.rule }}
{% endfor %}
```

---

For  example, the test variables

```yaml
  vars:
    firewall_v4_input:
       - {group: "haproxy", rule: "-p tcp -m multiport --dport 80,443 -j ACCEPT"}
       - {group: "haproxy", rule: "rule_12"}
    firewall_v4_output:
       - {group: "haproxy", rule: "-p tcp --dport 3000 -d 10.0.0.5 -j ACCEPT"}
       - {group: "haproxy", rule: "rule_22"}
```

give

```yaml
shell> cat 99-haproxy 
-p tcp -m multiport --dport 80,443 -j ACCEPT
rule_12
-p tcp --dport 3000 -d 10.0.0.5 -j ACCEPT
rule_22
```